# How would I display an Android app on a Touch screen TV and get the appropriate Motion Events to interact with the application?

Tags: android, google-tv, touchscreen

I have an interesting problem and was wondering how I would accomplish displaying an Android app on a large Touch screen TV so that users can interact with it. Imagine having something like Google Maps displayed on a standard TV that allowed you to swype, pinch to zoom and click on Points of Interest. What's a good way to do this?

I found this Lenovo concept (that's not for sale yet)

http://www.engadget.com/2012/01/08/lenovo-ideatv-letv-k91-android-ice-cream-sandwich/

And an Acer 21 inch Android device: [http://www.amazon.com/Acer-DA220HQL-21-5-Inch-Touchscreen-Desktop/dp/B00CHYKVPQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CHYKVPQ)

But I'd really like to just use a standard TV and have it hooked up to a standard Android Tablet/device/computer/Emulator that's running my application.

Many thanks.

Jared

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific. You can deploy your application to a Google TV. However, when publishing your app, you need some specific changes.

You can find detailed information about Google TV Android implementation from this link.
https://developers.google.com/tv/android/

Comment: Here is the offical launch of the Lenevo product at CES 2014 that was mentioned in the original post: http://gigaom.com/2012/01/08/lenovo-android-tv-k91/

Comment: I guess, this is not Google TV box. The TV is with Android. No need for tv box. If so, it is easy to write an app for it. You need to add support just for multiple screens. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html